# How to add/sub int to a BYTE type?

Tags: c++, types, integer, byte

I've a struct defined this way:

```
struct IMidiMsg {
    int mOffset;
    BYTE mStatus, mData1, mData2;
}
```

and I set to `mData2` int values between 0 and 127, without any problem. But, if I add/sub int:

```
pNoteOff->mData2 -= 150;
pNoteOff->mData2 += 150;
```

I get weird results. I think due to the different type: it's BYTE, not int of course. (Note: BYTE is from `minwindef.h`)

Let say I've a `mData2` with value 114: how would you first sub 150 and than add 150, getting again 114?

Comment: Is `BYTE` the `BYTE` from WinDef.h?

Comment: It's from minwindef.h

Comment: What is the weird result that you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have negative values in a `BYTE`, as it is defined as `typedef unsigned char BYTE;` - it can only hold numbers between 0 and 255.

If you want to have negative values too, use `signed char`; that works between -127 and +128. Or just use a normal `int`. Saving bytes is not a good idea nowadays, with 32- or 64-bit architecture, it makes calculations slower if anything.

Answer (score 1):

> how would you first sub 150 and than add 150, getting again 114?

That is exactly what is supposed to happen. You start with 114, and you subtract 150 from a type capped at 255. Since 114 is less than 150, subtraction results in a "borrow", i.e. (256+114)-150=220.

When you add 150 to 220, so you get 370. Now the "carry" is dropped, so you get 370-256=114.

The same mechanism is at work here as in modulo arithmetic with any other cap. For example, if you consider single-digit decimal numbers, doing something like

```
3-6+6=3

3-6 --> (borrow) 13-6 --> 7
7+6 --> 13 --> 3 (drop tens)
```